# Transpose data to create a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table  with three columns :- name, col1, col2

I need to create another table with col1 as columns and col2 as values. Can someone give me an idea.

This is the source:

```
Name      col1         col2
details   Company      Microsoft
details   Employees    300
details   City         New York
details2  Company      Apple
details2  Employees    450
details2  City         Boston
```

I need a table for details like this

```
Company    Employees    City
Microsoft  300          NewYork
```

And another table for details2 like this:

```
  Company    Employees    City
    Apple      450          Boston
```

Comment: Not very clear, what's the use of column `name` for example?

Comment: Are you need one table as output or Separate table for each Distinct NAME column?  If yes, then why you need separate table specific to NAME column.. You are changing your question again and again...with each specific condition....Its better to put all your needs in question at once so that others can have clear idea what you requires

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but yes, i need different table for different name because each of this table will be used in different processes. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5b8dc/2/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your One column values as Table Column and Second column values as Rows like this way

First Approach:- [SAMPLE SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/743cf/2)

```
Select    
 MAX(case when col1 = 'Company' then col2 end) Company,   
 MAX(case when col1 = 'Employee' then col2 end) Employee,   
 MAX(case when col1 = 'City' then col2 end) City 
From test 
Group By name
```

**EDIT**

Second Approach :- [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94047/6)

```
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX), @Soucecolumn VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Soucecolumn = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',[' + [col1 ] + ']' FROM test FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT ' + @Soucecolumn + ' FROM test PIVOT (MAX(col2) FOR [col1 ] IN (' + @Soucecolumn + ')) AS pvt'
exec sp_executesql  @QUERY
```

Comment: thx, it works, but, what if i have n rows on col1 and different values for name. i want to put this in a sp.

Comment: see EDIT in answer, Second Approach

Comment: i get this error: The column name "value(col1)" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.

Comment: post your query which you trying to execute and get error? then I let you know, what the problem is